# Did I correctly calculate the time complexity of my solution?

Tags: algorithm, performance, data-structures, time-complexity

I've been trying to get better at data structures an algorithms by learning online and solving leetcode problems. I'm also trying to understand how to calculate the time complexities of my algorithm to figure out how I can improve them. I just finished the LeetCode question: [Third Maximum Number](https://leetcode.com/problems/third-maximum-number/). I assume my solution isn't too optimized, as it's only faster than 45% of the solutions. But I think it is still running in linear O(n) time. Here is my code:

[image: My work for my calculations for the time complexity of my algorithm]

Did I calculate this correctly? Does my algorithm run in O(n)? Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: Please don't share images of code, paste the code directly.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I'll do this next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there is no doubt that the complexity of your algorithm is `O(n)`. But, it is not the exact complexity of your code and there are couple of places you can improve. Here is the list:

1. The complexity of `set` operation is `O(1)`, but in the worse case (when you get hash collision occur in every insertion) the complexity would be raised to `O(n)`. Thus, the over all complexity of your `list(set(nums))` could be `O(n^2)`.
2. To find the third maximum number, you run `O(n)` loop for three times. Clearly, the `Big-O` notation for this would be `O(n)` but practically you are running for `3 * n`.

You can consider improving in this areas. Please keep in mind, although two algorithms with the same `Big-O` complexity could have different actual runtime due to the optimization in the code. I further thought about this problem and found this problem can be solved by running only a single loop over the `n` numbers. Here is my `C++` code:

```
class Solution {
public:
    int thirdMax(vector<int>& nums) {
        const long long int MIN = ((long long int) 1 << 60) * (-1);
        int sz = nums.size();
        long long int mx1, mx2, mx3;
        mx1 = mx2 = mx3 = MIN;
        
        for(int n : nums) {
            if(mx1 <= n) {
                if(mx1 == n) continue;
                mx3 = mx2;
                mx2 = mx1;
                mx1 = n;
            }
            else if (mx2 <= n) {
                if(mx2 == n) continue;
                mx3 = mx2;
                mx2 = n;
            }
            else if (mx3 < n) mx3 = n;
        }
        
        if(mx3 == MIN || mx2 == MIN) return mx1;
        return mx3;
    }
};
```

The runtime of this code is `4 ms` and it is faster than `97.13%` of C++ online submissions for this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers! I'll keep messing around with the problem and try to implement a O(n) vs. O(3n) solution